# how to remove all html tag inside textarea but tag must be working

Tags: php, html, textarea

The code below does not remove the html tags inside the textarea, also, inside of it other tags must be working.

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="kreditor_address" rows="7" cols="40" style="resize: none;">
<?php
echo strip_tags("<b>DK Finans ltd</b>", "<b>"); 
?> 
</textarea>
```

Comment: `<?php
echo "<b>DK Finans ltd</b>"; 
?> ` Simply echo this out put  **DK Finans ltd** with bold text

Comment: `$text = "<b>DK Finans ltd</b>";
 echo strip_tags($text, '<html>');`

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter of `strip_tags` is for the tags you want to allow in the string not the tags to be stripped.

```
echo strip_tags("<p><b>DK Finans ltd</b></p>", "<p>");
```

**Output**

```
<p>DK Finans ltd</p>
```

> allowable_tags - 
>   You can use the optional second parameter to specify tags which should not be stripped.

[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)